# Groups of Zeroes in a Data Set - Determine Their Lengths?

Tags: r, vector

I have several large data sets of animal movements where their pauses (zero magnitude vectors) are of particular interest. Here is an example of the kind of data I am interested in analyzing:

```
x <- Mod(c(rnorm(2),replicate(3,0),rnorm(4),replicate(5,0),rnorm(6),replicate(7,0)))
length(x)
```

This example has 27 elements with strings of zeroes situated among the data.

I would like to:

1. Count how many groups of zeroes that exist in the data
2. Determine the length of each group of zeroes and store this "report" in its own data frame.

Thank you!

Comment: You want `rle()`, like so: `with(rle(x), lengths[values == 0])`.  That gives you three groups, with 3, 5, and 7 values in each group, respectively.

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly what I need. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: `rle` is probably the intuitive and simple answer. But if you're a masochist you could do: `zeros <- cumsum(x!=0)[x==0]; as.numeric(table(zeros)); length(unique(zeros))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
data.table(x)[,if(all(!x)) .N ,rleid(!x)]
#   rleid V1
#1:     2  3
#2:     4  5
#3:     6  7
```

#### Update

If we need a two column "ID", "values", a modified option with `rle` would be

```
ID <-  inverse.rle(within.list(rle(!x), {
          values[values] <- paste0("z", seq_along(values[values]))
          i1 <- !grepl("^z", values)
          values[i1] <- paste0("n", seq_along(values[i1])) }))
d1 <- data.frame(ID, values = x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

head(d1, 10)
#   ID     values
#1  n1 1.05402614
#2  n1 0.08924472
#3  z1 0.00000000
#4  z1 0.00000000
#5  z1 0.00000000
#6  n2 0.34346380
#7  n2 0.46807736
#8  n2 0.22253354
#9  n2 0.30781598
#10 z2 0.00000000
```

Comment: Terrific suggestions! How about this: is there a way to collect and label each interval and store them in a data frame? I envision the final result to have two columns: one with the values and another that serves as an ID column. For instance, let's say the first string of values is nonzero, so it would be labeled "n1" for "nonzero string #1". The next string of values is all zeros, so it would be labeled "z1" for "zero string #1". The third string is nonzero, so it would be labeled "n2" for "nonzero string #2"... and so on...

Comment: The application of this analysis: how long are the animals resting (zeroes) following a burst of activity? What was the median speed during this burst and its duration? Once I can get the data frame labeled as described above I am quite certain I can carry out the rest of the analysis.

Comment: @TavaroEvanis  I updated the post.  Please check if that is what you envisioned in the description.

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I had in mind! This allows me to analyze locomotive behavior on a very fine scale. Many thanks!